# Why I Cannot Change A Field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, web, sql-update

```
"UPDATE transaksi 
 SET nama ='".$nama."', kamar = '".$kamar."', hp = '".$hp."',
     masuk = '".$masuk."', keluar ='".$keluar."', tagih ='".$tagih."', 
     jumlah ='".$jumlah."', bawa ='".$bawa."', bayar ='".$bayar."'  
 where kamar ='".$kamar."'"
```

I made this code and it works normally until I realized that the field "kamar" cannot be changed.
I wonder where is my fault because another fields can be changed when I activate this method.

Please help

Comment: Is the kamar column the primary key?

Comment: You're setting `kamar` to the same value it already has, since the `WHERE` clause only selects those rows for updating.

Comment: kamar is not primary key. What do you mean, Barmar ?

Comment: The variable you're using to set kamar is the same variable you use in the where clause. A change to kamar is therefore not possible with such a query

Comment: You have `SET kamar = $kamar` and `WHERE kamar = $kamar`. So `kamar` won't change because it already has that value.

Comment: But I've tested the query directly to localhost and it's going well.